# how can i scroll until a number of elements and gather data

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scroll, selenium-chromedriver, scrollview

I want to scroll until a certain number of same elements and gather their data

ive tied using loop but i get this exception 
`StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

```
driver.get("https://unsplash.com/search/photos/beach")
img = []
scroll = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2Mc8_')
for num in scroll[0:200]:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(num).perform()
#    ai = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",num)
    print (scroll)
    href = num.get_attribute("href")
    img.append(href)
print (len(img))
```

Comment: _...until a certain number..._ How many? What does the _Test Specification_ says?

Comment: its a part of a program where i have to collect 2000 links but i need to scroll to get such number

Comment: I don't see code trial for _2000 links_ rather you are counting `len(img)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple approach.

```
url = 'https://unsplash.com/search/photos/beach'
driver.get(url)
while len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("figure[itemprop='image']"))<2000:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//figure[@itemprop='image'])[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//figure[@itemprop='image']")))
```

Comment: this could work but i needed not to use xpath, Thank You